# Error in Angular: Can't bind to 'ngForOf' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular

I can't use directive *ngFor. I've searched all the posible solutions, but I can't fix it.

Here is my code:

sobre-nosotros.component.html:

```
<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;" *ngFor="let d of test">
    <img src="assets/img/1.jpg" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
      <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

sobre-nosotros.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CochesInterface } from '../interfaces/CochesInterface';
import { CochesServiceService } from '../services/coches-service.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sobre-nosotros',
  templateUrl: './sobre-nosotros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sobre-nosotros.component.css']
})
export class SobreNosotrosComponent implements OnInit {

  public test:number[]=[1,2,3,4,5];

  constructor(private cochesService: CochesServiceService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    
  }
}
```

And I've following error:

[image]

My app.module

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './components/header/header.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './components/footer/footer.component';

import { InicioComponent } from './inicio/inicio.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    InicioComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I don't know what could be the problem. Is a project recently created, so I don't touched anything.

Comment: Where is `SobreNosotrosComponent` declared in? Did you ensure that the module that the component is declared in has imported `CommonModule` from `@angular/common`? (This is because only the app's main module should import `BrowserModule` as it should only be imported once)

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `CommonModule` as  `ngIf` and `ngFor` are declared there.

Ref:
[Frequently-used modules](http://%5Bhttps://angular.io/guide/frequent-ngmodules%5D%5B1%5D)

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your `SobreNosotrosComponent` in the `app.module`, like you did `InicioComponent`. Then stop and relaunch `ng serve` process. This should fix it.